# One value out of many not restoring as it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, state-restoration

I have a handful of elements in one of my view controllers for which I have set up restoration so that values are saved when navigating between views and also when the program is terminated. All of the values are saving as desired, with the one exception of the following, which is a BOOL that reverts to "0" every time the view is reopened.

This is where I declared the variable in my view controller header:

```
@interface TankViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

{
BOOL bigTank;
}
```

Here is the code in my view controller implementation file. All of the other elements are saved in this same fashion and work, whereas this one keeps reverting to NO/"0":

```
// Restoration of user fields
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
// tank selector segmented control for equation
    [coder encodeBool:bigTank forKey:@"bigTankEquation"];


// these are necessary to set the NSUserDefaults if the user terminates the app without going back to the menu first

// tank size state
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:bigTank forKey:@"bigTankRestore"];

[super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{

// tank size state
bigTank = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"bigTankEquation"];

[super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

}

// this will save states when going back and forth between views

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

// tank size state
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:bigTank forKey:@"bigTankRestore"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // checks whether or not the view has launched already. If it has not, viewDidLoad handles initialization and NSUserDefaults are updated to change flag to YES. Subsequent loads will restore using NDUserDefaults for view-to-view restore and encode/decode for background/terminate/restart restore

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"TCVHasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // view already launched

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

// tank size state
        bigTank = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"bigTankEquationRestore"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"This is a subsequent launch of the Tank Calculator View");

    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"TCVHasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        // This is the first launch ever
        NSLog(@"This is the first launch of the Tank View");
    }



}
```

What's really crazy is that my console immediately after returning to the view looks like this:

```
2014-02-17 02:38:48.301 myapp[5086:60b] bigTank value = 0
2014-02-17 02:38:48.302 myapp[5086:60b] bigTank current Default = 1
```

How the default is being saved as 1, but the value is 0 is incomprehensible to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To me it look like you are saving and reading to user defaults with different keys.

Comment: Oh man. Maximum tunnel vision from looking at the same code for too long. Of course now that I look at it here, it is way too obvious and I feel like an idiot. Problem solved. Thanks for your help.